# Ionic 2 multiple ion-item in a row

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to show 4 `ion-items` in my `ion-list` in a row.

Since I'm using Bootstrap, I tried to do:

```
<button class="col-sm-3" ion-item *ngFor="let player of players">
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img [src]="user.photoURL">
    </ion-avatar>
    {{ user.name }}
  </button>
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: are you trying for 4 items or buttons?

Comment: @SurajRao 4 items, I don't care if it's a button or not.

Comment: @MohanGopi How does digital keyboard has anything to do with my question??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can manually set the width of each column by using the *Explicit Column Percentage Attributes* like this:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col width-25>
        <!-- item 1 -->
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-25>
        <!-- item 2 -->
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-25>
        <!-- item 3 -->
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-25>
        <!-- item 4 -->
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Or just add `ion-col` dynamically, and they will expand to fill their row, and will resize to fit additional columns, like this:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let player of players">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <img [src]="user.photoURL">
            </ion-avatar>
            {{ user.name }}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

You can find more information about the Explicit Column Percentage Attributes [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid).

**UPDATE**

As of [Ionic 3.0.0](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2017-04-05), the way to achieve the same with the new grid would be something like this:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-3>
        <!-- item 1 -->
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3>
        <!-- item 2 -->
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3>
        <!-- item 3 -->
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3>
        <!-- item 4 -->
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

So the `width-25` attribute needs to be replaced by `col-3`.

Comment: Good catch! I've updated the answer. The idea is that you can include whatever you want inside the `ion-col` elements, and that's what will allow you to place elements in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ion-item>
<ion-row>
<ion-col *ngFor="let player of players">
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img [src]="user.photoURL">
    </ion-avatar>
    {{ user.name }}
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

You dont really need bootstrap for this.
Check [this tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-look-at-the-grid-system-in-ionic-2/) and [here](http://blog.ionic.io/layout-the-cool-way-using-the-ionic-2-grid-component/)

Comment: I did try it, the `col-sm-3` don't work and it shows one item each line

Comment: oh.. sorry now i get it.. will update the answer.You want a grid

Comment: doese't `ion-item` need to be used inside a list? and is it possible to create a new item each user and not one item for all?